# Android Geocoder and Addresses List - Google Maps API. ( Out of Bounds exception )

Tags: android, google-maps

So, I tried to resolve it by myself but I failed. I hope that someone here will be able to help me. My MapsActivity (showing the address on the screen)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)  {

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String adres1 = extras.getString("adres");
        System.out.println("Adres w Maps_Activity: " + adres1);

        mMap = googleMap;

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        java.util.List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(adres1, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
            double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
            System.out.println(longitude);
            System.out.println(latitude);


 LatLng adres = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(adres).title("Podgląd na " + adres1));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(adres, 17));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(adres));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(adres, 17)); 


    }








}
```

It's working good but only for simple addresses without spaces, commas, dots etc.
For example it's displaying the map and zooming into the address properly if it's in a one word format -  "name_of_city","name_of_country" etc...
If you type "name_of_street number, city", I'm getting an  `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` 
on those lines

```
double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
            double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
```

Does anybody knows how to solve that? I want to display on the map more complicated addresses, not only cities and countries.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162747/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-invalid-index-0-size-is-0/41162863#41162863

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :D !